# SELECT WHERE {column} = CASE WHEN {expression} THEN NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, case

I have this code which is part of a stored procedure

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
/* A few subqueries, about 100 lines */
WHERE    (cartera.ClaSucursal = @pIdSucursal OR @pIdSucursal = -1)
AND      (cartera.ClaAsesorActual = 
         CASE
             WHEN @pIdAsesor > 0 THEN @pIdAsesor
             WHEN @pIdAsesor = 0 THEN NULL 
         END
         OR @pIdAsesor = -1)
/* Rest of my code, about 200 lines */
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

Basically I have a parameter called `@pIdAsesor` and depending on its value there can be three possible outcomes.

1. `@pIdAsesor = -1` which brings me all entries regardless of the Id value
2. `@pIdAsesor = sumId` which brings me all entries with given Id
3. `@pIdAsesor = 0` which brings me all entries with NULL as the Id

Outcomes 1 and 2 work flawlessly, but scenario 3 doesn't bring back results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` isn't a value - it's the lack thereof. `null` is never equal to anything (not even another `null`), but you can check for it explicitly with the `is` operator.

You could ditch the `case` expression and construct this logic with a series of `or`s:

```
AND      ((@pIdAsesor = -1) OR
          (@PIdAsesor = 0 AND cartera.ClaAsesorActual IS NULL) OR
          (@pIdAsesor = cartera.ClaAsesorActual))
```

Comment: Maybe `...(@pIdAsesor > 0 and @pIdAsesor = cartera.ClaAsesorActual)` to avoid any other negative values?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it's a question of requirements really. I see `@pIdAsesor > 0` in the OP's code, but on the other hand, the requirement "@pIdAsesor = sumId which brings me all entries with given Id" doesn't seem to exclude negative IDs.

Comment: Mureinik Yes! all three scenarios are working! Thank you so much! @AlwaysLearning, I dont understand, you mean for it not to bring me all results if given lets say -2? it doesnt, I just tried.

Comment: @ArturoLozano We don't know the contents of your database. My comment was based on your case clause `WHEN @pIdAsesor > 0 THEN @pIdAsesor` which suggests that `@pIdAsesor` or `cartera.ClaAsesorActual` have the potential to be negative values other than `-1`. If neither of those can be other negative values then there is no concern.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Great observation! it would indeed prevent possible catastrophes, fortunately `cartera.ClaAsessorActual` only holds positive numbers greater than 0. Thank you for that insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=` for `null` in case when result comes null but `= null` doesn't work. You have to use `is null`.